# Getting exact time of button/key input

Tags: unity, input

Is there a way to get the time of an input event (a key or button press) to a higher degree of accuracy than the Update call, maybe by subscribing to input events and handling them immediately?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need such highly accurate input? Your purpose will tell us how accurate exactly the input needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`OnGUI()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html) and [`Event.current`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-current.html) you can get the exact moment that a key is pressed. `OnGUI()` is one of the few things that is not tied to framerate like the update function is. This is why using `OnGUI()` will give you a much more accurate time than the update function.

You can then do something like this:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if (Event.current.isKey)
    {
        Debug.Log("Key pressed at time " + Time.realtimeSinceStartup);
    }
}
```

which will put the time a key was pressed, released, and typed in console.

I'm using [`Time.realtimeSinceStartup`](http://Time.realtimeSinceStartup) here because this reports time based on the system timer unlike Time.time does.

Comment: Does this require a workaround to make sure some GUI always has focus, so these events can be used outside of the context of GUI?

Comment: All this requires is that the game has focus. There is no need for any UI elements, canvases, or event systems.

Comment: is `OnGUI` called more frequently than `Update` calls OP mentioned? This seems to me to have the same accuracy. The event system might be faster: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Events.html (Was hoping to find an answer where that is tested, to see if it's worth implementing it this way)